# Удаление из таблицы связи

Tags: sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Существует 2 таблицы:  а) Таблица объектов (id,object,...,categor_id), содержит в себе информацию ид,название(object),...,категорию.  б) Таблица категорий (id,name,id_parent), содержит в себе информацию ид,название,ид_родителя.   В первой табличке видно что есть 3 объекта(пакета) и их принадлежность к определенной категории.    Во второй таблице видно что в категории есть связь Дерево-Доска-Шебка Дерево-брусок Металл-гвоздь Металл-шуруп   Мне нужно удалить категории, по которым нет товаров, то есть, должна удалиться связь `Дерево-брусок`, но, нельзя удалить главного родителя Дерево или Металл, а так же усложняет то, что есть длинная связь Дерево-Доска-Шебка, она не дает возможность просто удалить категории которые не встречаются в таблице объектов, так как она удалит нужную связку Дерево-Доска.   Ответ можно и в теории, как бы вы поступили для решения данной задачи.[image: Таблицы]

Comment: *как бы вы поступили для решения данной задачи.* Я бы 1) НЕ удалял пустые категории. Зачем? 2) Если таки упёрлось, сменил бы структуру хранения. Дерево же - значит, или nested set, или хотя бы materialized path. В такой структуре проверить детей на пустоту - раз плюнуть. 3) А если ещё и структуру не сменить - ну тогда выносим логику удаления на сервер, пишем ХП, которая проверит ветку на пустоту, и только в случае положительного результата - удалит. Или проще - тупо итерационно прочистит всё дерево категорий от пустых листьев.

Comment: Спасибо, тоже ориентируюсь на php, мне думаю не сложно будет такое реализовать.

Comment: *тоже ориентируюсь на php* Ни в коем разе! Никаких пэхапэ, всё только на сервере БД.

Comment: А почему так негативно? Слушаюсь, сложным запросом тогда сделаю)))

Comment: Любая задача должна решаться тем инструментом, который предназначен именно для таких задач. А не тем, что под руку подвернулся. С данными - работает сервер БД. *сложным запросом тогда сделаю* Не запросом. Хранимой процедурой. Достаточно,кстати, простенькой. Впрочем, если версия MySQL восьмая, то можно и запросом.